# Dynamically adding datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Student here in the process of practicing .js and jquery and I had a question.
I'm creating a kanban and am trying to add a date picker for each new card I make.

Here's my script that adds a new card to the board:

```
$(function() {
        $( '.sortable' ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        }).disableSelection();
        $('.addbutton').click(function() {
            var newItem = $('#new').val();
            $(this).closest('div.container').find('ul').append('<li class="card"><input type="checkbox"> '+newItem+ ' <p>Due Date: <input id="datePicker3" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"></p></li></form></input>');
        });
    });
```

I've got some cards on my board that use

```
 $( function() {
        $( '#datePicker' ).datepicker();
    } );
```

But I'm not sure where to begin to add dynamic date picker who's id wont be the same. I've looked around and saw some examples using buttons but I'm trying to get it to be contained within the new card automatically- 
The HTML portion looks like this, FWIW

```
<div>
<div class="container" style="background:linear-gradient(180deg, steelblue, lightsteelblue);">
    <h2>New Issues</h2>

    <ul class="sortable connectedSortable">
        <form action=""><li class="card"><input type="checkbox">Do CS 81 Homework
            <p>Due Date: <input id="datePicker" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"></p>

        </li>
    </ul></form></input>
    <button onclick="hide_cb();">Delete</button>
    <div class = "center">
        <div class="addnewcard, centered">
            <input type="text" id="new" value="" placeholder="Add text for a new card here!"/>
            <input type="button" id="btnAddNew" value="Create New Card" class="addbutton"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could I get some help please? Very truly appreciate it :)

Comment: Why not use the class name instead? `$( '.datePicker' ).datepicker();`?

Comment: Your id does not seem to be dynamic to me. You have used the name 'datepicker' as the id. So how is it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a class instead then you don't have to worry about it being unique

```
$(this).closest('div.container').find('ul').append('<li class="card"><input type="checkbox"> '+newItem+ ' <p>Due Date: <input class="datePicker" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"></p></li></form></input>');
```

and then your jquery

```
$( '.datePicker' ).datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

First your html is not nested right. ul, form and input closing tags are not right.
For your js:

```
$('.addbutton').click(function() {
            var newItem = $('#new').val(),
                newLi = $('<li class="card"><label><input type="checkbox" /> '+newItem+ ' <p>Due Date: <input class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" /></p></li>');

            $(this).closest('div.container').find('ul').append(newLi);
            newLi.find('.datepicker').datepicker();
        });
```